# Javascript access parent properties

Tags: javascript

How can I get parent options?

I would like to access a global myObject options

```
var myObject = {    
  method: function(){
    this.options = {};
  },      
  property: {    
    propertyMethod: function(){
       alert(this.options);
    }     
  }    
}    
myObject.method();
myObject.property.propertyMethod();
```

Comment: Generally you can't do that. But if `myObject` is global, then you can always do `myObject.options` in child object.

Comment: @freakish: That (slightly expanded) is an *answer*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, actually I wasn't 100% sure so I've decided to make it a comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean, you want to access `myObject`'s `options` property from within `property.propertyMethod`, there's no way to do that except by taking advantage of the fact that `propertyMethod` is a closure over the `myObject` variable, e.g.:

```
var myObject = {    
  method: function(){
    this.options = {};
  },      
  property: {    
    propertyMethod: function(){
       alert(myObject.options); // <=== Change is here
    }     
  }    
}    
myObject.method();
myObject.property.propertyMethod();
```

...which isn't usually a good idea. :-) Instead, you may want to design your object differently. For instance:

```
var myObject = (function() {
  var obj = {
    method: function(){
      obj.options = {};
    },      
    property: {    
      propertyMethod: function(){
         alert(obj.options);
      }     
    }    
  };
  return obj;
})();
myObject.method();
myObject.property.propertyMethod();
```

That way, you're using the execution context of the call to the function. But if you're going to do that, maybe take it to the next step:

```
function makeObject() {
  var obj = {
    method: function(){
      obj.options = {};
    },      
    property: {    
      propertyMethod: function(){
         alert(obj.options);
      }     
    }    
  };
  return obj;
}
var myObject = makeObject();
myObject.method();
myObject.property.propertyMethod();
```

...so you can make more than one. Or even make a true constructor:

```
function MyObject() {
  var obj = this;

  obj.method = function(){
    obj.options = {};
  };      

  obj.property = {    
    propertyMethod: function(){
       alert(obj.options);
    }     
  };
}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.method();
myObject.property.propertyMethod();
```

...although since you're not leveraging the prototype, there's no much reason to make it a constructor function.

Comment: thanks, this is a great explanation, but what method would you use?

Comment: @user634177: It depends on your needs. If you only need one of these objects, probably the second one (using the anonymous maker function). If you need more than one, I'd probably refactor a bit and use a constructor function (but not everyone likes constructor functions, the `makeObject` version is fine too).

Comment: @user634177: And of course, if you don't mind `myObject` being global, you can just use `myObject` as in the first example. If your declaration isn't at global scope, just change it to `window.myObject =` rather than `var myObject =`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call` to bind `this` to `myObject`

`myObject.property.propertyMethod.call(myObject);`